# Make an array of input name attributes Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

How can I make an array using a loop which contains the name attributes of inputs inside a form tag, using javascript.

This is my code so far, but it doesn't seem to be working and I have looked at other similar questions to no avail.

```
      <script type="text/javascript">
      var inputnames[];
      for (var i = 0; i < document.getElementsByTagName('input').length; i++)
      {
      inputnames[document.getElementsByTagName("input")[i].name]
      };
      document.write(inputnames)
      </script>
```

Comment: inputnames.push(document.getElementsByTagName("input")[i].name); ?

Comment: inputnames.push(document.getElementsByTagName("input")[i].name) should add the name to the array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you're not actually adding the values to the array. Change

```
inputnames[document.getElementsByTagName("input")[i].name]
```

to

```
inputnames.push(document.getElementsByTagName("input")[i].name)
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you need to get list of elements. 
Than you can iterate over them.

And do not query DOM each iteration. If you are not expected DOM mutation you can get it once and iterate over it.

```js
var inputnames = [];
var elems = document.getElementsByTagName('input');

for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
  inputnames.push(elems[i].name);
};
document.write(inputnames)
```

```html
<input name="first" type="text" />
<input name="second" type="radio" />
```

Comment: `document.getElementsByTagName` does not return an array, but it can be iterated somewhat like an array

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss agree.

Answer (score 0):

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
  var inputnames=[];
  for (var i = 0; i < document.getElementsByTagName('input').length; i++)
  {
  inputnames.push(document.getElementsByTagName("input")[i].name);
  };
  alert(inputnames);
  </script>
```

Comment: the question isn't tagged jQuery, so not sure why you offer that.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty close, I would not use the `document.write` there, not sure what you want to do  but this logs it in the console.

```
var inputnames = [];
for (var i = 0; i < document.getElementsByTagName('input').length; i++) {
  inputnames.push(document.getElementsByTagName("input")[i].name);
}
console.log(inputnames);
```

Here is another alternative

```
var inputnames = [];
for (var item of document.getElementsByTagName('input')) {
  inputnames.push(item.name);
};
console.log(inputnames);
```

Alternate 2: use map.call to treat it is an array.

```
var inputnames = [];
var nodelist = document.getElementsByTagName('input');

Array.prototype.map.call( nodelist, function(n){
    inputnames.push(n.name);
});
```

Alternate 3  get only inputs with a name attribute and push those (avoids blanks in the array)

```
var inputnames = [];
var named = document.querySelectorAll("input[name]");
Array.prototype.map.call( named, function(n){
    inputnames.push(n.name);
});
```